# How to get NFC status through ADB shell command?

Tags: appium-android, adb

I am automating an app in that I am turning on NFC through shell command:SVC NFC enable

Now I need to check it's statuswhether NFC has been turned on or not ?

Anyway I can do it through adb shell.